# unbiased estimator of the area of the circle

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, estimation, sampling

the radius of a circle is measured with an error of measurement which is distributed normal with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$,$\sigma^2$ unknown.Given $n$ independent measurements of the radius , find an unbiased estimator of the area of the circle.

By using *Maximum Likelihood Estimator* I found

$$\hat\sigma^2=\frac{\sum e_i^2}{n}$$

where $r=r_o+e_i$ is the radius of the circle and $e_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Then i am stucked to find the unbiased estimator of the area of the circle

Comment: Look what you've writen: $r$ has zero mean?

Comment: @leonbloy I apology.I have not understood what does it indicate if $r$ has $0$ mean ?

Comment: Suppose I say to you: I have some circles here, their mean radius is zero. Would you swallow that?

Comment: The mean radius (itself a positive variable) cannot have zero mean, what has zero mean is the _error_, i.e. if $\hat{r}=r + e$ where $\hat{r}$ is the measured radius, $r$ is the true radius (constant) and $e$ is the measurement error. You know that $E(e)=0$

Answer (score 3):

Surely one could use MLE, but it turns out it is not unbiased, but that is easily rectifiable. Here is a possible approach.

If $R\sim R_o+N(0,\sigma^2)$, then $R\sim N(R_o,\sigma^2)$. We have two unkown parameters here ($R_o$ and $\sigma$) and we wish to estimate a function of $R_o$, namely $A(R_o)=\pi R_o^2$. By the MLE method, it is well know that the estimator for $R_o$ in $N(R_o,\sigma^2)$ is given by:

$$ \hat{R}_o=\sum_i\frac{R_i}{n}=\bar{R}$$

By the invariance principle ($A$ is is 1 to 1 in our parametric space for $R_o$), the maximum likelihood estimator for $A(R_o)$ is given by $A(\hat{R_o})$, that is:

$$ \hat{A}=\pi\left(\sum_i\frac{R_i}{n}\right)^2=\pi\left(\sum_i\frac{R_i^2}{n^2}+\sum_{i\not=j}\frac{R_i R_j}{n^2}\right)$$

Therefore, suppousing identically distributed independent $R_i$, we have

$$\mathbb{E}[\hat{A}]=\frac{\pi}{n^2}(n\mathbb{E}(R^2)+n(n-1)\mathbb{E}[R]^2)=\frac{\pi}{n}(\sigma^2+R_o^2+(n-1)R_o^2)=\pi R_o^2+\frac{\pi \sigma^2}{n}$$

So, apparently there is a $\pi \sigma^2 /n$ bias factor. But, as I said, this is easily rectified:

$$ \hat{A}=\pi \bar{R}^2-\frac{\pi }{n}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_i(R_i-\bar{R})^2\right)$$